# Cannot select top row from the column sql from nested select

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

I have 2 tables

Products

```
PID  NAME                ORIGINAL_PRICE    DISCNT_RATE
---- -----------         --------------    -----------
p001 stapler                      9.99          .1
p002 TV                           249           .15
p003 camera                       148           .2
```

Purchases

```
  PUR# EID PID  CID         QTY PTIME     TOTAL_PRICE
------ --- ---- ---- ---------- --------- -----------
100001 e01 p002 c001          1 12-AUG-17      211.65
100002 e01 p003 c001          1 20-SEP-17       118.4
100003 e02 p004 c002          5 08-OCT-17        4.95
100005 e04 p007 c004          1 15-OCT-17       119.2
100006 e03 p008 c001          1 12-OCT-17       349.3
```

Find the pid and name of each product that has been sold the most in terms of the total quantity. Display the corresponding total quantity (header: “total quantity sold”). Use column format to change the header to “total quantity sold”.

Sol:

What I have done so far is

```
 SELECT Max("Total") AS "HS", pid 
 from (Select pid, sum(qty) as "Total"
 from purchases group by pid);
```

I am not able to process the information as expected if any help can be provide..

P.S: Its not a homework

Comment: Can you share the sql you are using to generate the data?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Sum and group by for obtain the total value and TOP 1  on ordered result for get the max

IN SQL SERVER

```
  select TOP 1 a.PID, sum(b.QTY) as "total quantity sold"
  FROM Products AS a
  INNER JOIN Purchases AS b on a.PID  = b.PID
  GROUP BY a.pID
  ORDER BY sum(b.QTY) DESC
```

Using the max from the subselect as you have done  (not using group by for get a row only)..  can produce  wrong result because in most of the db this is not allowed  or can show a PID casually obtained  for the the result set of the subselect  ..

if you don't want use the TOP  (limit for row) you should use the max value for filter wit proper where the subselect and obtain the correct couple PID, MAX tital

Answer (score 0):

For the pid and name of the product that has sold the largest quantity:

From Oracle 12c on there is a `fetch` feature that would limit the output to one row:

```
SELECT pu.pid, pr.name, sum(pu.qty) as "total quantity sold"
FROM PURCHASES pu
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS pr on pu.pid = pr.pid
GROUP BY pu.pid, pr.name
ORDER BY sum(pu.qty) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
;
```

For earlier versions of Oracle supporting `row_number() over()` (or for other databases with that same function support):

```
SELECT pid, name, "total quantity sold"
FROM (
      SELECT pu.pid, pr.name, sum(pu.qty) as "total quantity sold"
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sum(pu.qty) DESC) AS RN
      FROM PURCHASES pu
      INNER JOIN PRODUCTS pr on pu.pid = pr.pid
      GROUP BY pu.pid, pr.name
      ) 
WHERE RN = 1
;
```

But both those approaches assume there is just one row to report. In a larger set of data there could be more then one row sharing the highest sum of quantity. To return all such rows use `dense_rank() over()` instead e,g,:

```
SELECT pid, name, "total quantity sold"
FROM (
      SELECT pu.pid, pr.name, sum(pu.qty) as "total quantity sold"
           , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sum(pu.qty) DESC) AS RNK
      FROM PURCHASES pu
      INNER JOIN PRODUCTS pr on pu.pid = pr.pid
      GROUP BY pu.pid, pr.name
      ) 
WHERE RNK = 1
;
```

Note, in the sample provided there PIDs p004/p007/p008 are missing from the products table. That I assume is just an omission from the question.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/694c3/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE PURCHASES
    (PURno int, EID varchar2(3), PID varchar2(4), CID varchar2(4), QTY int, PTIME timestamp, TOTAL_PRICE numeric)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO PURCHASES (PURno, EID, PID, CID, QTY, PTIME, TOTAL_PRICE)
         VALUES (100001, 'e01', 'p002', 'c001', 1, '12-Aug-2017 12:00:00 AM', 211.65)
    INTO PURCHASES (PURno, EID, PID, CID, QTY, PTIME, TOTAL_PRICE)
         VALUES (100002, 'e01', 'p003', 'c001', 1, '20-Sep-2017 12:00:00 AM', 118.4)
    INTO PURCHASES (PURno, EID, PID, CID, QTY, PTIME, TOTAL_PRICE)
         VALUES (100003, 'e02', 'p004', 'c002', 5, '08-Oct-2017 12:00:00 AM', 4.95)
    INTO PURCHASES (PURno, EID, PID, CID, QTY, PTIME, TOTAL_PRICE)
         VALUES (100005, 'e04', 'p007', 'c004', 1, '15-Oct-2017 12:00:00 AM', 119.2)
    INTO PURCHASES (PURno, EID, PID, CID, QTY, PTIME, TOTAL_PRICE)
         VALUES (100006, 'e03', 'p008', 'c001', 1, '12-Oct-2017 12:00:00 AM', 349.3)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
    (PID varchar2(5), NAME varchar2(70), ORIGINAL_PRICE int, DISCNT_RATE numeric)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO PRODUCTS (PID, NAME, ORIGINAL_PRICE, DISCNT_RATE)
         VALUES ('p001', 'stapler', 9.99, .1)
    INTO PRODUCTS (PID, NAME, ORIGINAL_PRICE, DISCNT_RATE)
         VALUES ('p002', 'TV', 249, .15)
    INTO PRODUCTS (PID, NAME, ORIGINAL_PRICE, DISCNT_RATE)
         VALUES ('p003', 'camera', 148, .2)
    INTO PRODUCTS (PID, NAME, ORIGINAL_PRICE, DISCNT_RATE)
         VALUES ('p004', 'p004 missing from sample', 0, 0)
    INTO PRODUCTS (PID, NAME, ORIGINAL_PRICE, DISCNT_RATE)
         VALUES ('p007', 'p007 missing from sample', 0, 0)
    INTO PRODUCTS (PID, NAME, ORIGINAL_PRICE, DISCNT_RATE)
         VALUES ('p008', 'p008 missing from sample', 0, 0)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT PID, NAME, "total quantity sold"
FROM (
      SELECT pu.pid, pr.name, sum(pu.qty) as "total quantity sold"
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sum(pu.qty) DESC) AS RN
      FROM PURCHASES pu
      INNER JOIN PRODUCTS pr on pu.pid = pr.pid
      GROUP BY pu.pid, pr.name
      ) 
WHERE RN = 1
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/694c3/3/0)**:

```
|  PID |                     NAME | total quantity sold |
|------|--------------------------|---------------------|
| p004 | p004 missing from sample |                   5 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT PID, NAME, "total quantity sold"
FROM (
      SELECT pu.pid, pr.name, sum(pu.qty) as "total quantity sold"
           , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sum(pu.qty) DESC) AS RNK
      FROM PURCHASES pu
      INNER JOIN PRODUCTS pr on pu.pid = pr.pid
      GROUP BY pu.pid, pr.name
      ) 
WHERE RNK = 1
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/694c3/3/1)**:

```
|  PID |                     NAME | total quantity sold |
|------|--------------------------|---------------------|
| p004 | p004 missing from sample |                   5 |
```